# Python3 Qt5 MainWindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I have an application flow which looks like this. At startup a MainWindow is shown and asks the user to choose a project or create a new one. After a project is created or chosen from the list, I want to close this MainWindow and open another MainWindow.

In my `main.py` the code looks like this:

```
app = QApplication([])

ui_project_list_view = ProjectListView()
ui_project_list_view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Now I want to close the first main window (`ui_project_list_view`) and open the other main window (`ui_project_view`). This code is called from within `ui_project_list_view`.

```
ui_project_view = ProjectView()
ui_project_view.show()
main_view.close()
```

No matter in which order I show or close, the application quits. How should I design my "window-flow" ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open most programs like Word or Excel- or QtDesigner for example- you'll see a blank main window initialize, and then a popup will appear asking you to choose your project.

If you wanted to apply this to your code, the `ProjectView` should be the main window and the `ProjectListView` would be the popup. The `ProjectView` would call this after initializing, in a `setup` function perhaps. After `ProjectListView` finishes, then `ProjectView` would just need to update the screen with the information that `ProjectListView` has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will go with your recommended work flow.